# How do I get records where the data started at a particular day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL code to show `id` and `date` for records where the date started at 23/xx/xx

Is this correct?

```
SELECT id,
       date
FROM xxx
WHERE date = yyyy/mm/23;
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use? And no, it is not correct.

Comment: probably innodb if he doesn't know himself.

Answer (score 0):

See [DAYOFMONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth)

```
SELECT id, date FROM your_table 
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(date) = 23
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This will not return a dataset that contains records where the date occurred after the 23rd chronologically, only values that occurred on that date. Not sure if that's a requirement or not...

Comment: @MarkW, I think that is correct. Get records that happened on the 23rd of any month/year.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague question. Is this for the current month? Is it for every month? If you want data on or after the 23rd of the current month then you'll need

```
SELECT id,
       date
FROM xxx
WHERE date >= '2015/07/23'
```

If you want data after the 23rd of every month then try:

```
SELECT id,
       date
FROM xxx
WHERE DAY(date) >= 23
```